# update duplicate email values except first one in the sql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains column email, in that column I have a few duplicate values.

What I want is to update duplicate values adding the existing value +BREAK string to it except the first one.

Example, before:

```
1email
1email
2email
3email
3email
```

after:

```
1email
1email+BREAK
2email
3mail
3email+BREAK
```

My table has a lot of columns, i just give simple example of what i want

I tried this code but its fixed and doesent work:

```
UPDATE users AS t1
   SET email = email + '+BREAK'
 WHERE rrn(t1) =
       (SELECT MAX(rrn(t2))
          FROM users AS t2
         WHERE email  = 'rr@hotmail.com')
```

Comment: What is rrn? Please add all relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use multiple-table [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) syntax.

```sql
UPDATE users t1
JOIN ( SELECT email, MIN(id) id
       FROM users t2
       -- WHERE email  IN ( {emails list} )
       GROUP BY email ) t3 ON t1.id > t3.id AND t1.email = t3.email
SET t1.email = CONCAT(t1.email, '+BREAK')
;
```

`id` is primary key or another unique-valued expression. In current query all rows with the same `email` except the row with minimal `id` value will be updated.

Comment: this add  '+ BREAK' to all my email values, so its not good?

Comment: @HHHHHHT Of course, there is no restriction by email value now. Uncomment WHERE  condition and specify needed value or values list.